# manage authentication with tokens created with OAuth2 in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony

my message is based on this message [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748106/how-to-manage-authentication-with-token-in-angular-js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEngO.png)
I have a backend with PHP5(Symfony2) and a front end with (angularJS) I have succeeded to create tokens with the backend,but I got a problem with angularjs,I have to get the token from the URL and to put it in every request to get client lists per example,this is what I did:

the controller:signin.js

```
'use strict';
  // signin controller
app.controller('SigninFormController', ['$scope','$http', '$state','$localStorage','authorizationInterceptor', function($scope, $http, $state,$localStorage,authorizationInterceptor) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.authError = null;
    $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.authError = null;
      // Try to login
    $http({method: 'POST', url: 'myURL/oauth/v2/token?client_id=clientID&client_secret=clientSecret&grant_type=client_credentials'})
   .success(function(response){
     if (response.data.user) {  
     $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); 
     $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
     $scope.posts = data; // response data 
     var token = this.$window.sessionStorage($scope.posts.access_token);
     console.log(""+token);
     console.log("success");
     $state.go('app.home');}
   })
   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.authError = 'Email or Password not right';
    console.log("data error ...");
  });

    };
```

and my services :access-services.js

```
.factory('Security', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var token;
        function login(email, password) {
            return $http.post('/auth/login', {email: email, password: password})
                .then(function (response) {

                    if (response.data.token) {
                        token=response.data.token;
                    }
                });
        }

        function getToken(){
            return token;
        }

        return {
            login:login,
            token:getToken
        }; }])
.factory('authorizationInterceptor', ['Security', function (Security) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                var token=Security.getToken();
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if (token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
                }
                return config;} }; }]);
```

but this is what I get in console:
[image]

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to angular to use the token interceptor. This can be done at the app config phase

```
yourApp.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authorizationInterceptor");
});
```

I suggest you read the following series of articles. Though they are written targeting ASP.net MVC, concepts presented are universal

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks Chintana Meegamarachc,I have add those lines to my config file:thanks Chintana Meegamarachc,I have add those lines to my config file:.config(['$httpProvider',function ($httpProvider) {
           $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
        }]) but I get this error : Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: TokenInterceptorProvider <- TokenInterceptor <- $http <- $translateStaticFilesLoader

Comment: can you change it to $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authorizationInterceptor");

Comment: always the same problem :( -> Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- Security <- authorizationInterceptor <- $http <- $translateStaticFilesLoader

Comment: Its probably because you are using 'Security' service as dependency to the interceptor and the interceptor is being called from Security service when it does the http call. The best thing to do is to create another service to hold the token and use it with both the 'Security' service and the inteceptor

Answer (score 1):

use a token interceptor like this:

```
app.factory('TokenInterceptor', function($q, $window) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
        config.headers['X-Access-Token'] = $window.sessionStorage.token;
        config.headers['X-Key'] = $window.sessionStorage.user;
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";
      }
      return config || $q.when(config);
    },

    response: function(response) {
      return response || $q.when(response);
    }
  };
});
```

and then use it in your app.config like this

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
```

Comment: thanks @Viki and the controller,should I call the service from the controller??

Comment: You dont need to call anything, once you add 
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');

every request will have the token injected in header if the sessionstorage has token.

Look how @Chintana Meegamarachchi pushed interceptors in $httpProvider.

Sorry, new to stackoverflow and not used to this editor.